# Нормализованная база данных не соответствует требованиям

Tags: база-данных, ms-access, теория

Есть учебное задание по нормализации до НФБК базы данных с такими полями: *НомерСтудента*, *ФИОСтудента*, *КодПреподавателя*, *ФИОПреподавателя*, *Кафедра*, *Предмет*, *Оценка*. Требования: один студент может получить только одну оценку по предмету, один преподаватель может вести несколько предметов с кафедры и наоборот, на кафедре может быть несколько преподавателей (но не наоборот), на кафедре может быть несколько предметов (но не наоборот).

Как попытался сделать это задание:

1. 1НФ. Производим выравнивание, получаем таблицу с перечисленными полями, первичный ключ (далее выделяю его полужирным) **НомерСтудента** и **Предмет**.
2. 2НФ. *ФИОСтудента* зависит только от **НомерСтудента**, *Кафедра* зависит только от **Предмет**, остальные поля: *КодПреподавателя*, *ФИОПреподавателя*, *Оценка* зависят от **НомерСтудента** и **Предмет**.
3. 3НФ. Устраняем транзитивную зависимость: **НомерСтудента** и **Предмет** -> *КодПреподавателя* -> *ФИОПреподавателя*. Выделяем таблицу с полями **КодПреподавателя** и *ФИОПреподавателя*, то, что осталось в «старой» таблице — **НомерСтудента**, **Предмет**, *КодПреподавателя*, *Оценка*.
4. НФБК. Вроде ничего делать не надо.

В итоге остались такие таблицы:

1. **НомерСтудента**, **Предмет**, *КодПреподавателя*, *Оценка* (Внешние ключи — первые три поля)
2. **КодПреподавателя**, *ФИОПреподавателя*
3. **НомерСтудента**, *ФИОСтудента*
4. **Предмет**, *Кафедра*

И тут получается, что преподаватель может вести предметы с разных кафедр, а не с одной, как требуется. (В таблицу с ключом **НомерСтудента** и **Предмет** можно внести любого преподавателя). Так и должно быть или где-то ошибка? И если не ошибка, то почему так получилось и как сделать так, чтобы база данных соответствовала требованиям?

Comment: Схему БД приведите

Comment: @Alex78191 у меня пока нет реализации в СУБД, но могу привести итоговые таблицы. Это скорее теоретический вопрос.

Comment: итоговые приведите, я про логическую схему говорил. Можно через по схемы проектировать

Comment: Набор полей изменять нельзя? Например, добавить ид_кафедры, ид_предмета?

Comment: @IvanIvanov Я так понимаю, введение id делается лишь для экономии памяти и после того, как всё уже спроектировано. Вообще, можно считать, что *Кафедра* и *Предмет* — числа. А так, конечно, можно добавить поля.

Comment: @Alex78191 то, что сейчас в обновлённом вопросе — это то, что нужно? Если нет, напишите подробнее, что я могу сделать.

Comment: Вообще-то по 1НФ не в атрибут нельзя хранить массив и надо создать для ФИО 3 отдельных поля.

Comment: @Alex78191 это же не «массив» (многозначный атрибут), а скорее «структура» (составной атрибут). Если бы у студента могло бы быть два ФИО, то был бы массив. В любом случае, указанную проблему разбиение атрибута на 3, мне кажется, не решает.

Comment: конечно не решает, да, не прав

Comment: Надо сделать таблицу связывающую преподавателей с предметами, которые они ведут. Вам же наверняка нужна информация о том, кто что ведет вне зависимости от того, ставил он уже оценки по этому предмету или нет. Но проблемы "строго одна кафедра преподавателя" это конечно не решает. Такие вещи решаются обычно уже потом, триггерами. По крайней мере чисто архитектурного решения не вижу

Comment: @Mike У меня вроде бы [получилось](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9311a9/1) даже без триггеров. Но таблица `ПредметПрепКаф` не находится в НФБК. Мне, правда, непонятно, невозможно ли это вообще и находится ли она хотя бы в EKNF. В английской [вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce–Codd_normal_form#Achievability_of_BCNF) вроде бы похожая таблица.

Comment: @pocketgulag предмет-преподаватель-кафедра нарушает правило, что предмет может быть только на одной кафедре, в случае если это у вас отдельная связующая таблица. Если же поля преподаватель и кафедра вы хотите поместить непосредственно в таблицу предметов то выходит, что один предмет сможет вести только один преподаватель, а мне показалось по тексту задачи, что это не так

Comment: @Mike мне кажется, вы не посмотрели мой SQLFiddle. Там же как раз закомментирован запрос, который пытается поместить предмет с другой кафедрой в таблицу, и который не работает из-за внешнего ключа в таблице `Предмет`.

Comment: Да, я не заметил вашего fiddle. Но она нарушает 3НФ т.к. в этой связующей таблице имеется прямая зависимость кафедры от предмета. А говоря человеческим языком налицо избыточность данных т.к. кафедра с предметом связана в двух таблицах

Comment: @Mike Для нарушения 3НФ вроде бы нужна транзитивная зависимость (ключ и два поля, как минимум), а в таблице `ПредметПрепКаф` только ключ из двух полей и _Кафедра_.  Вот НФБК точно нарушается — *Кафедра* зависит от *Предмет*. Насчёт избыточности согласен.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0  пример посмотрите: сотрудник=пепод, отдел=предмет, телефон=кафедра. И в любом случае назначение НФ устранить какую бы то ни было избыточность. Если избыточность есть - значит НФ точно нарушена, а какая конкретно, это уже не имеет особого значения

Comment: @Mike в том примере ключ — _Сотрудник_, а у меня _Код преподавателя_ и _Предмет_. Да и предмет не зависит же от преподавателя, там связь «многие ко многим». Вообще в [статье](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce–Codd_normal_form#Achievability_of_BCNF), которую я приводил ранее, в конце есть таблица, похожая на мою. Там аналогичная избыточность, но написано, что отношение находится даже в EKNF. Не знаю, применимо ли это к моей таблице.

Comment: Так проблема в том, что кафедра зависит от предмета. причем однозначно. А такого быть не должно, если уж два поля есть, то одно от другого однозначно зависеть не должно

Comment: Так у того, кто дол задание спроси. То, на что нужно обратить внимание нужно писать в правой части fiddle